# Cloud Access by a Group

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

I have a group of people who want to access and drop files in the Ubuntu One folder.

I crudely gave everyone my ID and Password to access the files, but there must be a more elegant way for anyone at any time to access or deposit files in the cloud storage.

How do I get each individual access from their own computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu One allows you to share folders with others, with the choice of whether or not to allow them to modify the folder.

To share a folder, go to https://one.ubuntu.com/files and open the folder you'd like to share (you need not navigate anywhere to share the root directory of your Ubuntu One storage). Then click on **Share this folder**, enter the emails of those whom you'd like to share with, and check or uncheck **Allow modification** according to your preference.

Comment: It didn't work, the system just says "loading, please wait...", but nothing happens, and I have to try again after stopping the process(waited for the loading over 3 hrs)